# My Navigation controller requires pressing back twice in iOS5?

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, navigation, uinavigationbar

I have a Navigation controller in a storyboard, currently with two screens. Screen1 contains an opening logo and some buttons, and I have hidden the navigation bar at the top using:

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

in `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear:` (in `viewWillAppear` I have it set with animated:YES, so it slides off when coming back from other screens).

When I go to Screen2, I have:

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```

in the first view controller's `viewWillDisappear`, and the navigation bar slides in all nicely when that view comes on to the top of the navigation stack.

Problem is, when I tap back, the navigation bar animates off the right side of the screen, but Screen2 stays there, revealing another navigation bar underneath!

I can then tap back again and it will push Screen2 off and the main screen shall return, but this is not behaviour I want to pass on to any users, obviously!

Anyone had this issue before, or have any points on what might be the culprit?

Edit: I just found an error appearing when I run the iOS Simulator:

```
2011-11-02 19:29:13.548 TestHTML5[10261:f803] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <LessonViewController: 0x6c5e960>.
```

This happens when I click the button to go the the second view (LessonViewController).
Hopefully that might be the thing to crack this, anyone know?

Comment: I call animated uinavigaitionbars in my apps.  Have you tried just using the viewWillAppear one?  Your code is correct, but my hunch (why I am not posting as an answer) is that when you call it twice it literally makes 2 navigation bars!  So delete the one in the viewDidLoad and run again.

Comment: @CodaFi Just tried it, like you said, and it didn't make a difference.
It did however mean that when the app initially loaded, the navigation bar was present on the screen and then slid back off immediately. Not quite a look I'm aiming for, on the first load :)

I also checked how it acts if I took it out of `viewWillAppear:`, and it still doubles up, as well as (of course) leaving a nab bar on the home screen when I return.

Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: OK, try this: In my app, I didn't have the navigation bar animations in any other controller but the one that made it disappear (i.e., controller A does nothing and controller B makes the animations happen) so in your controller B, put this in viewWillAppear:     [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];

and this in viewWillDisappear:     [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];

Comment: Ok, gave it a shot, but it made no difference to the situation unfortunately. I still get `2011-11-02 19:29:13.548 TestHTML5[10261:f803] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <LessonViewController: 0x6c5e960>.` when I click to each new view and still have to click back twice :/

Comment: hmm... the problem is that the simulator is logging your original error now.  It means when you tap it twice, it sends an animation twice, thus unbalancing the BOOL that is navigationbar.hidden; Do a push with no animation, tell me if there are any errors.

Comment: I have just tried commenting out all the `setNavigationBarHidden:` lines, and i can see when I press the button to go to the second view, a back button appears, then the push to the next view occurs, bringing yet another back button with it. I'm comparing to other projects where I have used navigation controllers but can't find any other difference, apart from using `setNavigationBarHidden:` in this one.

Comment: Just tried with animation off, when I click back, the whole view animated off the right to reveal a copy of the whole view underneath it, before i can then continue back to the home screen. The `Unbalanced calls` error does not appear when i click the button to push the next view now, however.
I believe the `Unbalanced calls` error has been happening all along though, I discovered last night that the debugger on my laptop was only displaying fatal errors in the console for some reason, not warnings, but I have moved onto the desktop now (same Xcode and SDK versions).

Comment: OK, now add them back in, one at a time.  First add the one that hides it in the viewWillAppear of the second view controller.  Try the push, quit.  If it succeeds, then add in the showing method in the viewWillDisappear method.

Comment: Guess what, I found it. In my IBOutlet methods for the buttons, if I comment out the two lines telling the buttons to push to their next respective views, the whole problem doesn't happen. Make sense to you? It doesn't to me... but now it works, and thats all I can really ask for, I guess. Thank you so much for your help anyway!

Answer (score 2):

I found my IBActions, which contained:

```
SecondViewController *X = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"X"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:X animated:NO];
```

on each were causing the view to double up or something like that. When I commented these two lines out in each IBAction, the problem disappeared.

Thanks heaps to @CodaFi for helping me through possibilities for this, to be honest, this solution doesn't make sense to me, even thought I can see it working here.

Comment: Good on you!  Best of luck with this.